# SQL XML DIFF on attributes

Tags: sql, xml

I have a XML field in a table and want to set a trigger to store changes in another table.
I want to know for example that the attribute "url" changed from "http://example.com/" to "http://newurl.com" and when.

This is what I have now:

```
DECLARE @XML1 XML
DECLARE @XML2 XML

SET @XML1 = 
'<NewDataSet> 
<Employee>
<EmpID>1005</EmpID>
<Name> keith </Name>
<DOB>12/02/1981</DOB>
<DeptID>ACC001</DeptID>
</Employee>
</NewDataSet>'

SET @XML2 = 
'<NewDataSet> 
<Employee>
<EmpID>1005</EmpID>
<Name> keith </Name>
<DOB>12/02/1981</DOB>
<DeptID>ACC002</DeptID>
</Employee>
</NewDataSet>'


;with XML1 as
(
  select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
         T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value
  from @XML1.nodes('/NewDataSet/Employee/*') as T(N)
),
XML2 as
(
  select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
         T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value
  from @XML2.nodes('/NewDataSet/Employee/*') as T(N)
)
select coalesce(XML1.NodeName, XML2.NodeName) as NodeName, 
       XML1.Value as OldVal, 
       XML2.Value as NewVal,
       GETUTCDATE() as changed
from XML1
  full outer join XML2
    on XML1.NodeName = XML2.NodeName
where coalesce(XML1.Value, '') <> coalesce(XML2.Value, '')
```

But it only works for node values, and I want it to work for attributes too.

Example of a XML File where I want it to work:

```
<crawlsetup>
  <go param="" url="http://www.example.com/index.php">
    <match param="" match="href=&quot;(/job[^&quot;]+)&quot;" url="http://www.example.com$1" save1="" save2="" save3="">
        <match param="" match="href=&quot;(/job[^&quot;]+)&quot;" url="http://www.example.com$1" save1="" save2="" save3="" />
        <next match="" url="$1" />
    </match>
  </go>
</crawlsetup>
```

There might be several  attributes, and I want to detect changes in all attributes.

Can someone help me on this?
Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select only one attribute (e.g. url) of an element use this XPath expression :

```
from @XML2.nodes('/crawlsetup/go/@url') as T(N)
```

To select all attributes of an element use this one :

```
from @XML2.nodes('/crawlsetup/go/@*') as T(N)
```

Comment: thank you so much!! what about all the attributes of all the elements?

Comment: You're welcome. To select all attributes of all nodes, refer to the answer provided by @Mikael Eriksson. You might as well have a look at [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms256086(v=vs.100).aspx to further explore on XPath expressions, especially the section on Location Paths

Comment: PS : you can accept the answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence in the nodes function. Add `/NewDataSet/Employee/@*`.

```sql
;with XML1 as
(
  select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
         T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value
  from @XML1.nodes('/NewDataSet/Employee/*, /NewDataSet/Employee/@*') as T(N)
),
XML2 as
(
  select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
         T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value
  from @XML2.nodes('/NewDataSet/Employee/*, /NewDataSet/Employee/@*') as T(N)
)
select coalesce(XML1.NodeName, XML2.NodeName) as NodeName, 
       XML1.Value as OldVal, 
       XML2.Value as NewVal,
       GETUTCDATE() as changed
from XML1
  full outer join XML2
    on XML1.NodeName = XML2.NodeName
where coalesce(XML1.Value, '') <> coalesce(XML2.Value, '')
```